# Saving painting app data to cope with interruptions on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, image-processing

I'm making an iPhone bitmap painting app. I want to support about five 1024x768 layers (~15Mb of data). My problem is that I do not know what strategy to use for saving the user's document to cope with my app being interrupted.

My document file format at the moment is to save each layer as a .png file and then save a short text file that contains the layer metadata. My problem is that, if the app is interrupted by something like a phone call, I'm unlikely going to have enough time for my app to be able to save all the data to disk as saving all the .png files can take ~10 seconds. What options do I have?

I've considered adding an autosave feature that would be called every five minutes. In the worst case, the user will lose a few minutes of work if the app fails to save on interruption (which isn't ideal).

An idea I've considered is to keep track of which layers have changed since the last autosave and only update the layer files that need to be updated. This means that, when interrupted, my app might only need to save one layer in the typical case. However, the worse case is still having to save several layers.

I'm not sure what to do. On a practical note, I've noticed many popular iPhone painting apps with good reviews will lose the current document progress if interrupted with a phone call. I'm beginning to doubt there is a way to solve this particular problem and that I might just have to go with something less than ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IOS4 SDK provides [support](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) for long-running background tasks, which would be the perfect place to save your layers. From the documentation:

> You can use task completion to ensure that important but potentially long-running operations do not end abruptly when the user leaves the application. For example, you might use this technique to save user data to disk or finish downloading an important file from a network server.
>
> Any time before it is suspended, an application can call the [beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:) method to ask the system for extra time to complete some long-running task in the background. If the request is granted, and if the application goes into the background while the task is in progress, the system lets the application run for an additional amount of time instead of suspending it. (The [backgroundTimeRemaining](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/backgroundTimeRemaining) property of the UIApplication object contains the amount of time the application has to run.)

Comment: My concern with this approach is that because my task will be holding onto a lot of memory, it may be more likely that the OS will kill it to reclaim memory. It's also not clear on how likely this approach is to succeed in general. Am I being too cautious or is this likely to work well?

Comment: I have never used background tasks myself, so I can not speak for how likely it is to work. In general, the OS should only be killing your app as a last resort. You have a chance to free unused memory when a `didReceiveMemoryWarning` event is fired, so perhaps you can jettison some non-critical things when that happens, so as to hang on to your layers for longer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is feasible (you don't state how the user interacts with the layers, or indeed if this interaction is transparent from their perspective), but as a suggestion why not simply save the "active" layer out (via a background thread) when the user switches layers, as you'd then only need to save a single layer when your app is backgrounded.

Comment: The UI will be similar to other Photoshop-style painting apps out there. I've considered an idea like yours but there are still nasty scenarios to consider where several layers are modified quickly by the user. The main one is if the user paints to layer 1, then layer 2, then layer 3 (where the system saves the previous active layer when switching layers), then undoes the last 3 actions (I'd like a decent undo/redo implementation like this), then paints on layer 3, I now have 3 changed layers that I need to save.

Comment: @rebeccamaher Hmm... perhaps not the best solution in this scenario from what you've said. That said, if the saves are on background thread(s), and you maintain the state information in your text file you could dispose of the unwanted pngs at a later time. As another thought, are you saving the whole layer, or just the portions of the layer that are used with the relevant coordinate offset? (Could be a reasonably trivial means of minimising data throughput.)